# Copy formula in filtered column with thousands of cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using a spreadsheet with 75000+ rows. The columns are filtered but the filtered columns still contains tens of thousands of cells. I want to copy a formula down all cells in the filtered column. What is the shortcut for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

Double click this little box when you have the cell containing the formula selected:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't like to drag down with the mouse:

1) Copy the cell with the formula

2) Navigate to the bottom of your table

3) Select the bottom-most cell in the column where you want the formulas to be

4) press `<CTRL><SHIFT><Arrow-up>`

5) Press paste

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you will be entering a formula immediately to the right of a column that is filled with data.

In that case, after entering the formula, type the following sequence of key strokes:

- <kbd>Left</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
- <kbd>Right</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

If the column to the left of the formula contains any cells that are blank, just keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> until you reach the end of the data and then continue with the keystrokes. If you over-shoot and reach the end of the spreadsheet, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> once to get back up to the end of the data.

Note that a final <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> will get you back up to the starting cell.