# Excel function to find and count all duplicates by row, excluding the first instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to create a report in excel that counts the number of duplicate rows, excluding the first instance of that row, in an imported sheet. I know that I could use "remove duplicates" in the Data menu for this, and I've also checked this solution: [Remove duplicate rows in Excel and count results](https://superuser.com/questions/1205009/remove-duplicate-rows-in-excel-and-count-results)

But my goal is to be able to fully view what the duplicates are and where they are in the spreadsheet. I also want the report to count the number of original entries and the difference with the duplicates removed, like so:

```
X1 aaaaaaa
X2 bbbbbbb
X1 aaaaaaa
X3 ccccccc
X4 ddddddd
X1 aaaaaaa

Total Entries: 6
Duplicate Rows: 2
Total Unique Entries: 4
```

Comment: Will you only every have one row that has duplicates?

Comment: I want to count duplicate rows, not duplicates within the row in different columns. Like in my example, rows 3 and 6 are duplicates, because both "X1" and "aaaaaa". I'm not trying to count just the instances of "X1" and "aaaaaa" separately.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Let me reword: Could you have a seventh row with `X4 ddddddd`, resulting in 7 total entries, 3 duplicate roes and 4 unique entries? Are you willing to accept a solution with a helper column?

Comment: Helper column(s) seems like a must, as presented.

Comment: Yes - that's exactly what I'm looking for. A helper column would be fine. The not-quite-there solution I'm currently using has one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in columns `A` and `B`, put the following formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)>1, COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,A1,B$1:B1,B1)-1,"")
```

And populate down.

This will sequentially number duplicates after the first one.

For the reporting cells use the following formulas:

Total Entries:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A7)
```

Duplicate Rows:

```
=MAX(C1:C7)
```

Total Unique Entries:

```
=COUNTA(A1:A7)-COUNTIF(C1:C7,">0")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! If I wanted to apply this to a large spreadsheet of indefinite size (for instance I'd want to take all of column A and column B without giving a numerical limit) how would I modify the COUNTIFS equation?

Comment: You just keep populating the `COUNTIFS` down until the last row. The reporting formulas can be changed to `=COUNTA(A:A)`, `=MAX(C:C)` and `=COUNTA(A:A)-MAX(C:C)` respectively

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1331314/copy-formula-in-filtered-column-with-thousands-of-cells/1331451) may be useful to populate a lot of rows with a formula

Comment: correct me if I am wrong here but are not the number of unique entries in your example 4?  OP asked to ignore first instance.  The number of duplicate entries could be taken as either 3  as [er your comment under the question?

Comment: @Forward Ed - facepalm  you're right  I'm on a phone right now, will fix the issue when i get to areal computer

Comment: The edit is done

Comment: After looking at this more, I have a question about applying the MAX function here for duplicate rows in a larger project. For instance, let's say there's another set of rows that has 4 duplicates, along with the 2 duplicates listed above. Wouldn't MAX return 4 here, instead of 6?

Comment: Assuming you have 4 duplicates of a new value(let's say `X5 eeeeeee`) then the max function will return `4`. If you have 4 duplicates of an existing value, it will return whatever the highest count is (ex: `6` for `X1 aaaaaaa` or `5` for `X4 ddddddd`)

Comment: Right, but let's say I wanted to count all of those duplicates - 6 for X1 aaaaaa and 5 for X4 dddddddd to get a final result of 11 total duplicates, how would I go about finding that sum?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(C1:C7,">0")`

Comment: If that replaces MAX, I don't think that would work, because that would include any instance of the result 1 - meaning the original entry wouldn't be excluded.

Comment: It will be because in column `C` the row of an original entry is blank and therefore `>0` will be false and so that row won't be counted

Comment: Right, the original row is blank, but the second instance of X1 has a result of 1, and the third instance has a result of 2. When totaled, wouldn't that would return 3, which includes the original entry? Or am I misunderstanding COUNTIF here?

Comment: `COUNTIF` only *counts* the instances where the given condition (`>0`) is true. You are thinking of `SUMIF`, which would, in this case, *sum* the numbers greater than `0` (assuming we were to give it the same condition)